# I have 2 plugins using the same wp_login action hook and one is not working

Tags: plugin-development, hooks, actions, s2member

so this is after a few hours investigating, I have s2member plugin and a custom plugin what happens is they are both using wp_login hook in this manner,
s2member:

```
add_action("wp_login", "c_ws_plugin__s2member_login_redirects::login_redirect", 10, 2);
```

and the custom plugin is using the same add action :

```
add_action( 'wp_login', array(&$this, 'login_success') , 100);
```

it didnt have any priority which is by default 10. so I changed it to 100 to see if it will resolve the issue but it did not. If I comment out that line in s2member my custom plugin works and logs the attempts to login.but then s2member plugin breaks. They are both separate files since they are different plugins. any ideas on how to resolve this? any suggestions would be greatly appreciated its my second night going crazy over this

Comment: What do the two callback functions look like?